# Print transcript ID and gene symbol from rna fasta to new text file

Tags: shell, unix, grep, fasta

I would like to print the transcript ID and gene symbol from the headers of an rna fasta file to a text file. I would like to end up with a text file with the first column being a transcript ID and the second being the gene symbol.

An example of the header:

```
>NM_001001258.1 Sus scrofa ATPase H+/K+ transporting beta subunit (ATP4B)
>XM_001924668.4 PREDICTED: Sus scrofa XK related 9 (XKR9), transcript variant X1, mRNA
```

I have been able to print the transcript ID to a text file:

```
grep "^>" GCF_000003025.6_Sscrofa11.1_rna.fna | tr -d '>' | awk '{print $1}' > test.txt
```

I have also been able to print the gene symbol to a text file:

```
grep "^>" GCF_000003025.6_Sscrofa11.1_rna.fna | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' > test.txt
```

I just was wondering if anybody could help me with combining this into one step to get a single file. I know I could just combine files, but I want to be sure that the IDs are coming from the same lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -rn '/^>/ s/^>([^ ]+).*\(([^)]+).*/\1 \2/gp'
XM_001924668.4 XKR9
NM_001001258.1 ATP4B
```

Here, First `/^>/` is to tell sed to only perform action on the matched line. Later captured the two strings of interest and referred them using `\1` and `\2` , called back referencing

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you have any suggestions for when the patterns of headers change in the same fasta? Another line from the same file: 
>XM_001924668.4 PREDICTED: Sus scrofa XK related 9 (XKR9), transcript variant X1, mRNA

Comment: @mrm check the `sed` souldtion which is added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F '[>)]| .*[(]' '{print $2, $3}' file
NM_001001258.1 ATP4B
XM_001924668.4 XKR9
```